# AWSCognito forgot password not working for non verified mobile number iOS

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

We are facing some problem while updating user password using forgot password option in Amazon Cognito. In one case, I updated my mobile number after that I didn’t verify my mobile number and move back to forgot password set up. We tried resetting the password here and we got an error as, “Cannot reset password for the user as there is no registered/verified email or phone_number”.

The expectation here is, I have to verify my mobile number in order to update my password. After this issue again we need to verify the user mobile number. Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the account is stuck in this state, AdminUpdateUserAttributes API can be called and the mobile number can be changed or can be marked as verified. From an end user perspective, end user will have to contact app developer to get around this.